# Pixelated result when trying to print a Node including an image from JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, printing

i stumbled upon a problem trying to print (to a printer or a pdf) an image through JavaFx. 
My code works and prints, but pixelates (downgrades quality) on every picture that i try to print.

My code is

```html
package testingprinting;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.print.PageLayout;
import javafx.print.PageOrientation;
import javafx.print.Paper;
import javafx.print.Printer;
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author me
 */
public class TestingPrinting extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws MalformedURLException {
 

       GridPane leftGridPane = new GridPane();
       
       leftGridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(25));    
       leftGridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(25)); 
       leftGridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(25));  
       leftGridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(25));   
       leftGridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(25));  
       leftGridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(25));   
       leftGridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(25));   
       leftGridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(25));   
       leftGridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(824));    
        
        VBox root = new VBox(1);
        root.getChildren().add(leftGridPane);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 800);
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("Print Testing");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        
       Image testImage = new Image(new File("C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\800px-Gull_portrait_ca_usa.JPG").toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
       ImageView testImageImageView = new ImageView();
       testImageImageView.setFitWidth(800);
       testImageImageView.setFitHeight(600);
       testImageImageView.setImage(testImage);
       leftGridPane.add(testImageImageView,0,0,9,1);  
        
        
       Button printButton = new Button("Print");
       root.getChildren().add(printButton);
       
        printButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        
        //Printer pdfPrinter = null;       
        Iterator<Printer> iter = Printer.getAllPrinters().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Printer printer = iter.next();
            if (printer.getName().endsWith("PDF")) {
      //          pdfPrinter = printer;
            }
        }
           

        Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
        PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.NA_LETTER, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
        double scaleX = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() / leftGridPane.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
        double scaleY = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight() / leftGridPane.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
        //leftGridPane.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scaleX, scaleY));
        
        
        
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        if(job != null){
        System.out.println("Job is not null");
        job.showPrintDialog(primaryStage); // Window must be your main Stage
        job.printPage(leftGridPane);
        job.endJob();
 }
        else { job.cancelJob();        System.out.println("Job is null");}
        }
        );       
        
      
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

and as you can see on the picture that i snipped 1. is from printing and the image is pixelated and 2. is from the code that i run and it is not pixelated.
[side by side comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSIny.png)

does any one has an idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can use `smooth` parameter : [javafx image documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html). I found also this documentation [Resizes image width preserving the ratio and using higher quality filtering method, cached to improve performance : Image « JavaFX « Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Resizesimagewidthpreservingtheratioandusinghigherqualityfilteringmethodcachedtoimproveperformance.htm) => so try : `testImageImageView.setSmooth(true);`

Comment: thank you my friend for your kind answer. The problem exist only when i try to print the image, on my project the image that is inside the node is looking great  when i run the project.Only when i press "print" the printed image is pixelated, on my monitor inside my note is looking great.

Comment: Maybe is what you want, to change the printer quality : [PrinterAttributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterAttributes.html) and [PrintQuality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrintQuality.html). I found an example of printing here : [Code Geeks - The JavaFX Print API](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/javafx-print-api/)

Comment: I have not found anything useful, thank you though :)

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is setting the print quality to high on the printer job. After you create the printer job call

```
job.getJobSettings().setPrintQuality(PrintQuality.HIGH);
```

I haven't had time to try it but it might help.

Comment: Thank you my friend for your replay, i tried it but did not work. I am the only one who has this problem ?

Comment: You could try setPrintResolution instead of setPrintQuality.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i tried it but the result is still pixelated.

Comment: It seems there are a couple of bugs reported to do with poor quality printing, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223372 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166194

Comment: So basically if you want to create a javafx application that in some point exports a print that includes a picture you get crappy quality and there is not any walk around.